What is the long stem growing out of my rose?
Out of my potted rose plant there is a fast growing long stem growing out of the main stem.
Its green, unlike the reddish hue of new growths.
It is fast growing and like an arrow.
It has leaves which look like rose and has thorns too.
But it doesn't look like the rest of the plant. What is it?


Is there a particular reason you tagged this "rosemary"? Rosemary is a culinary herb with needle-like leaves. It is unrelated to rose, the ornamental flowering shrub.

@R.M. actually I am using chrome in dark mode and for some reason this site is too bright and unreadable in dark mode, hence the mistake. Will remove the tag.

This is a sucker - a branch that grew from the rootstock, not the top part.
Roses (and other plants) are often grafted, i.e. on a rootstock of rose that has good rooting traits (to support the plant) scions of roses which show the desired flowers were transferred (those were bred and selected for their flowers, which may affect or neglect other traits).
Suckers mean that there was a bud on the rootstock that grew. You should remove it, because of its vigor (-> desired for the root system) it will tend to be dominant. But do not just cut it at the surface, you need to dig down a bit to the part where it branches off. Then either cut very close to the stem or tear it off - make a small horizontal cut just below the branch, then put down firmly.

There is no reason not to root it after it's removed and have a rose of a different name.

Yeeeees…. but it’s probably going to be vigorous, fast growing and with simple blossoms. And good luck if you want to get rid of it again if you planted it out.

@Wastrel How sweet will it smell?

It is difficult to be sure, but it seems the sucker has 7 leaflets per stem, indicating a wild rootstock. The cultivated rose probably has 5. If you let the sucker grow flowers, they will probably be small white 'dog roses', as @Stephie noted.
